# How to convert a collection of Vec<ndarray::Array1> into an Array2?

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust

I'm trying to create a 2D array from a `Vec` of 1D arrays using the ndarray crate. In the current implementation, I have `Vec<Array1<u32>>` as the collection of 1D arrays, and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to convert it to `Array2<u32>`. I've tried `from_vec()` on `Vec<Array1<u32>>` but it yielded `Array1<Array1<u32>>`. I thought of using the `stack!` macro, but I'm not sure how to call it on the above `Vec`. I'm using ndarray 0.12.1 and Rust 1.31.0.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not hugely familiar with `ndarray`, but it looks like you have to flatten the data as an intermediate step and then rebuild from that. An iterator would probably have been more efficient but I don't see a method to build from an iterator that also lets you specify a shape.

It likely isn't the most *performant* way to to this, but it does at least work:

```
fn to_array2<T: Copy>(source: &[Array1<T>]) -> Result<Array2<T>, impl std::error::Error> {
    let width = source.len();
    let flattened: Array1<T> = source.into_iter().flat_map(|row| row.to_vec()).collect();
    let height = flattened.len() / width;
    flattened.into_shape((width, height))
}
```

Note that it can fail if the source arrays has different lengths. This solution is not 100% robust because it won't fail if one array is smaller but compensated by another array being longer. It is probably worth adding a check in there to prevent that, but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Thanks! I tried flattening followed by reshaping and indeed the code worked! I'll think more about making it more performant, maybe rethink the data collection part where I create the Vec of Array1s in the first place as well (e.g. use Vec<Vec<T>> or collect into 1D Vec<T> in the first place instead, etc).

Comment: _"An iterator would probably have been more efficient"_ You will always need some container type `A` that implements `Data` to obtain an `ArrayBase<A, D>`. The standard `ReprOwned` type stores the elements in an array, and I don't think that there are ways to store them some other way. With that said, this answer is accurate (although indeed it _requires_ each vector in `source` to have the same length, otherwise chaos).