# Rust ndarray: Convert ArrayD to Array2

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust

Got an ArrayD which always has 2 dimensions, but is an ArrayD due to a calculation, need to change this to Array2 for storage.

Been looking through documentation, can't seem to find a way.

Is there a function to do it?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How to convert a collection of Vec<ndarray::Array1> into an Array2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53698503/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster This does not answer my question, the answer basically recommends iterating through every element and just copying them. This could be said of almost any data structure and I would presume the inference could be made I am looking for some reasonably efficient cast, not simply looping through every value (which is what I am doing already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a variable of type `ArrayD<f32>`, you can do:

```rs
// convert n-dimensional array into 2d array
let arr2d: Array2<f32> = arr2d.into_dimensionality::<Ix2>()?;
```

to convert it into a variable of type `Array2<f32>`.

If the dimensions don't match, it will throw an `ndarray::ShapeError` error.

---

also see: [ndarray documentation: into_dimensionality](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.15.3/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.into_dimensionality)